# Joint pdf as a product of two independent functions with dependent domain

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let us have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and their joint probability density function $f_{XY}(x,y)$. Let us assume that the function $f_{XY}$ can be written as a product of two functions $g(x)$ and $h(y)$. Then we say that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But what if the range of $y$ in the domain of $f_{XY}$ is dependent of $x$? For example $f_{XY}$ is defined on the set $\{|x|\leq 1,   |y| \leq x^2\}$, are $X$ and $Y$ still independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would write your joint density $f_{XY}$ as
\begin{align*}
f_{XY}(x,y) = g(x)h(y) \textbf{1}_{\{|x|\leq 1, |y| \leq x^2\}},
\end{align*}
which can no longer be split up into a product of functions depending only on one variable (since you can't factor the indicator into two indicators).

Comment: I see, thank you!